# How to group fields and change field order when using Switch Control in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, accessibility

As mentioned in #wwdc20-10019, you can use assessibilityNavigationStyle and assessibilityElements in UIKit to group fields and control the field tapping order when the user is using Switch Control. How can this be done in SwiftUI?  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can use .accessibilityElement(children: .contain) and .accessibilitySortPriority() to accomplish the desired result.